# cakephp find all posts that do not have specific habtm tag

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

Seems like a simple one but expected query doesn't work. The code below is just to illustrate my point. the actual model has some other conditions etc, but even when i strip them all away to something as basic as below i get no results.

I've tried it with linkable and with manual joins both.

```
$posts = $this->Post->find("all", array(
"conditions"=>array(
    "Tag.id !="=>$bad_id
),
"link"=>array("Tag")
));
```

$posts returns empty array.

Comment: You need to understand the/a sql that gives you your desired result, _before_ trying to write the query in cake

Comment: does `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tag_id != 1;` (substituting 1 for bad ID) give you results? That is, do you know it's the `find()` call causing a problem? If so, examine the SQL that Cake is generating. Is it correct? If not, read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html to understand how to get the correct SQL.

Comment: i've checked the sql syntax and everything looks appropriate. here you can see the real query returning zero results:
    SELECT `Brand`.* FROM `brands` AS `Brand` LEFT JOIN `brands_products` AS `BrandsProduct` ON (`Brand`.`id` = `BrandsProduct`.`brand_id`) LEFT JOIN `products` AS `Product` ON (`BrandsProduct`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`) WHERE `Product`.`id` != 15